# Adding an external link to the description in a new language snippet

Tags: visual-studio-code

I'm creating VS Code Snippets to the Bootstrat-Vue project and I'd like to have a direct link to the documentation in the snippet, or even better, the actual documentation in there.

Any thought on how I can achieve that?

Example:

```
"Boostrap-Vue Button": {
    "prefix": "bv-button",
    "body": [ 
        "<b-button :variant=\"${1|primary,secondary,success,outline-success,warning,danger,link|}\">",
        "\t${0}",
        "</b-button>"
        ],
    "description": "Button Documentation: https://bootstrap-vue.js.org/docs/components/button"
}
```